# How to add a search functionality to a PHP website, without using Java or Google site search?

Tags: php, search, yii

I would like to add a search field to my site. The site is based on PHP and the Yii framework. The web-server assembles multiple data (from files and APIs) before serving the resulting web-page (the web-server will get these pieces of data out of a MySQL database sooner or later, but it's just files at the moment, and API results).

Apache's Lucene could answer the problem, but there is no way to use Java on the server - I am on a shared Linux host.

Google site search (or bing's,..) could answer the problem, but I would like to have a fully-customizable search box, and add some results to the proposed result.

I could create my own search engine, indexing pages and using different weights according to where each piece of data come from, to have a precise result ; but I think there must be something out there that would be more efficient, and quicker to implement.

What'd be a way to add a quick search functionality to a PHP based website, without using Java or Google site search ?

Comment: Zend_Lucene, maybe? Are you on shared Linux hosting?

Comment: I prefer MySQL's `MATCH...AGAINST` function. It can be slow, but i find that when using it in conjunction with a search you can order the relevance of the search queries much better.

Comment: solr which is written with java runs of an index file and requires constant reindexing as content evolves. You could in replicate this by writing some php to scrape key content and write said content (with node) into a txt file and serve this up as your auto-complete prompts

Comment: @halfer it runs on a Linux server

Comment: OK. Are you on a _shared_ server? That is the biggest determinant of what you can, and cannot, run.

Comment: @SamuelCook - It would probably fit my actual needs, but if the the audience is too high, I am afraid that it deteriorate the site's performance.

Comment: @halfer yes, it is on a shared server ; not on a dedicated server.

Comment: @SamuelCook `MATCH` appears to be a workable solution, however, only for MyISAM tables unless the MySQL version is >= 5.6. An assumption I wouldn't want to make. Not to mention the problems associated with each of the storage engines. A dedicated system is hence presumably safer and better performance-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Zend Framework and consequently [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.html).  It's a pure PHP implementation of a faceted search.  You can define your own "document" (as an aggregate of your data), weight axes, and build indexes relatively straight-forwardly.  The downside, in my experience, is that it's much slower on indexing and query than (eg) solr.

**Update 1**
In response to comment, here's a link: [how I use Zend_Search_Lucene for spatial searches](http://www.ideacode.com/content/spatial-searches-with-zendsearchlucene).  The code there demonstrates a few things:

- Lines 54-62 show how to add a "document" to the index.  In this example, the document only has two fields (longitude & latitude), but you get the idea.  Just put this in a loop and add documents to your index.  In production operation, I keep track of changes to data, and update the index when any data going into indexed documents changes.  The initial import is very slow -- empirically, I found the algorithm is at least O(n log n) with a pretty big K, while solr was more like O(log n).
- Lines 42-52 show how to search an index.  This search is a bit more complicated than usual, because I have to encode longitude and latitude in the same way its encoded in the index.  The article explains *why* this has to be done, but suffice to say: if you just have text data, the index searching is not this hard.
- Line 40 is creating the index, which both the "add" and "search" mentioned in the previous two bullets requires.  Note that keeping the index on a fast medium (like SD storage) lowers the K in the algorithm, but it's still (empirically, not analytically) O(n log n).
- Lines 1-38 are the helpers needed to normalize a longitude and latitude into a format that Zend_Search_Lucene supports.  Again, if you have only text data, this complication isn't necessary.

**Update 2** Responding to the comment on performance.  Putting the index on a fast medium (SD, RAM disk w/ sync, whatever) speeds it up a bit.  Using [unstored](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.understanding-field-types) fields also helps a bit.  Both of these reduce the constant in the empirical O(n log n), but still the dominant problem is that n multiplier.  What Zend appears to do is, upon each add, re-shuffle most or all of the previous adds to the index.  As far as I can tell, this is the algorithm in play during index build and can't be modified.

The way I got around that n-multiplier was to use a [Zend Page Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.frontends.html#zend.cache.frontends.page) based on the stemmed query (so if someone types "blueberries", "blueberry", "blue berry", "blu bary", etc. they all get stemmed and fixed to the soundex phonetic "blue-bear-ee").  Common queries get almost instant results, and since the particular domain was read-heavy and insert-latent, this was an acceptable solution.  Obviously in general it's not.

In other circumstances, there is the [setResultSetLimit() method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.searching.html#zend.search.lucene.searching.results-limiting), which when used with scoring, will return results faster.  If you don't care about all possible results, just the top N results, then this is the way to go.

Finally, all this experience is with respect to Zend 1.x.  I do not know if this has been addressed in 2.x.

Comment: I tried using that quite a while ago for a DB of some 80k documents and I have to say generating the index and the subsequent search process was pretty … slow. To the point where indexing the initial batch takes upwards of 20 minutes in a decently spec'ed development environment. Could you elaborate a litte on your experiences and how you'd integrate this 'properly' into a Yii app?

Comment: @NikolasGrottendieck: Added to my answer some experience with Zend_Search_Lucene.  I don't use Yii, so I can't speak to "proper" there.  I would guess (stress the "guess" part) that you could download Zend, copy the Zend/Search/ directory into the vendor portion of Yii's framework, setup the include paths, and run with it.  You'll probably need a few helpers from other parts of Zend, but I doubt you'd need much.

Comment: Huh, so no advice on fast indexing/searching of data. Pity. Anyway thanks for elaborating on your answer!

Comment: @NikolasGrottendieck: Oh, didn't know you wanted a focus on performance. :)  Added some more details.

Comment: Well, as previously stated I fiddled with it some time ago and wanted a second opinion so to speak. Your original answer hinted at some knowledge about this so I figured why not see whether I can get any?. Guess I'll have another look at it in the future, thanks!

Comment: @NikolasGrottendieck: Well, hope I added some knowledge to the pool!  I really like Zend_Lucene_Search in theory, I just wish it were more practically performant.  ZF2 doesn't appear to have addressed the underlying issue.  I believe the merge portion is the culprit during build, and the [ZF2 code](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch/blob/master/library/ZendSearch/Lucene/Index/SegmentMerger.php) is same as ZF1.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot search engines. Personally I like [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/). But you need able to compile and run it on your (or remote) server. [You can look on php based search engines](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=open%20source%20php%20search%20engine) like [seekquarry](http://www.seekquarry.com/)

Comment: The Seek Quarry project is very interesting - and running on a few Mac Minis too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all the data(page name and url) in a database, and than you can make the search function using the `LIKE` operator in a MySql query:

```
mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE name LIKE '%keyword%'
")
```

Comment: Imo, `LIKE` is usually not flexible enough for keyword-based search, and its performance on large rowsets deteriorates faster than a dedicated indexed search system.

Comment: yes, but you can say that you dont depend by other website