# Tuning simple query with full-text searching

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I would like tuning my query with full-text searching.

I have two tables:

1. `artaolInventTable`

   a) IT_NAMEIDIDX (Unique, Non-clustered)

   - itemId
   - itemName
     (include column

   b) IT_IMPORTIDX (Non-unique, non-clustered)

   - importIndex

   c) IT_ITEMNAMEIDX (Unique, clustered)

   - itemName

   d) PK_ARTAOLINVENTTABLE (Unique, non-clustered)

   - itemId
2. `InventSumIntegration_ART`

   a) IS_AVAILIDX (Non-unique, Non-clustered)

   - availphysical

   b) IS_ITEMIDX(Unique, Clustered)

   - itemId
   - availphysical

First I have simple query:

Query 1

```
SELECT 
    it.ItemId, it.ItemName, it.ItemBrand, it.Amount, it.salesunit, it.importIndex
FROM 
    artaolInventTable IT
WHERE
    (CONTAINS(it.ItemName, '("Papier*" OR FORMSOF(THESAURUS, Papier)) AND ("ksero*" OR FORMSOF(THESAURUS, ksero)) AND ("A4*" OR FORMSOF(THESAURUS, A4))')
OR it.importIndex = 'IP000' OR it.ItemId = 'aaaa' )
ORDER BY
    it.ItemName
```

> CPU time = 32 ms,  elapsed time = 205 ms.

Execution plan looks good. To find every conditions in where clause SQL Server use indexes.

I added second table and my execution time increased to 51 sec!. Why? Is there problem with my indexes? How I should build it?

`INVENTSUMSHOPINTEGRATION` has invent stock value.

Query 2

```
SELECT 
    IT.ITEMID, IT.ITEMNAME, IT.ITEMBRAND, IT.AMOUNT, IT.SALESUNIT, IT.ImportIndex, 
    ISU.AVAILPHYSICAL 
FROM 
    ARTAOLINVENTTABLE IT 
JOIN 
    INVENTSUMSHOPINTEGRATION_ART ISU ON ISU.ITEMID = IT.ITEMID
WHERE 
    (CONTAINS(IT.ITEMNAME, '("Papier*" OR FORMSOF(THESAURUS, Papier)) AND ("ksero*" OR FORMSOF(THESAURUS, ksero)) AND ("A4*" OR FORMSOF(THESAURUS, A4))')
OR IT.IMPORTINDEX = 'IP000' OR IT.ITEMID = 'aaaa' ) AND (ISU.AVAILPHYSICAL >= 0)
ORDER BY 
    it.ITEMNAME
```

> CPU time = 51418 ms,  elapsed time = 51756 ms.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do it!** Database is a very bad place to search. Databases should store data and not search for data. In enterprise databases you can pay for full text search engine and it's ok. But don't use full search from databases like mysql or postgresql. Look at external search engines like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) (java) [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (java, on top of lucene) or very fast search engine [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) (c++). All have API for your favorite language. Solr use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to look in documents like word or excel. If you use Hibernate and Lucene is enough for you, look at [Hibernate-Search](http://hibernate.org/search/) - it's make a lot of things easier. If you don't able to install/setup you favorite search engine, try alternatives written as application in your favorite language. For php look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798631/how-to-add-a-search-functionality-to-a-php-website-without-using-java-or-google/19798711#19798711).

Comment: I forgot write I use MS SQL 2008R2. Full text search is part of engine of SQL SERVER.

I have to use .net 2.0 so I have problem to use lastes libraries.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MS-World. But in my experience join's, or's and bad indexes are performance killers. Sometimes temporary tables can increase your performance. Try to put your first query in a temp table and then filter with INVENTSUMSHOPINTEGRATION_ART.